# How to add series of DataPoint in the GraphView Library?

Tags: android, graph, kotlin, android-graphview

**ChartsActivity.kt**

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.jjoe64.graphview.series.DataPoint
import com.jjoe64.graphview.series.LineGraphSeries
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_charts.*

class ChartsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_charts)


    val datap = DataPoint[](
        DataPoint(0, 1),
        DataPoint(5, 1),
        DataPoint(6, 1),
        DataPoint(5, 6),
        DataPoint(2, 8)
    )

        val series = LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>(datap)

        graph1.addSeries(series)
    }
}
```

I am unable to write the correct series in the DataPoint Function. I want to use Kotlin, I have not found any kotlin code for the task.

How can I write the series to get the code working?

Answer (score 3):

The constructor for `Datapoint` requires `Double` type.

You can choose to pass `Double` or Create another function which accepts `Int` (integer) arguments.

```
fun DP(a: Int, b: Int): DataPoint {
        return DataPoint(a.toDouble(), b.toDouble())
    }
```

Then use it as follows

```
 val points = arrayOf( DP(0,1), 
                       DP(5,1),
                       ...
                       )
 val series = LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>(points)
```

Hope it helps.